# Robot Framework :I am getting "FAIL : NoSectionError: No section: 'default' " error when i connect the Robot Framework with MySql

Tags: python, mysql, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

Below my code to connect with Mysql database, but when i run the code its shows "FAIL : NoSectionError: No section: 'default' ". I want to know that how to connect with Mysql from Robot framework. i have installed Database Library and its fine but problem in code.

```
*** Setting ***
Library           Selenium2Library
Library           DatabaseLibrary
Resource          LoginRes.txt
*** Variables ***
#${PythonPath}    c:\Python26
#${url}           http://localhost/dt_qa/

*** Test Cases ***  
DT Login
    [Tags]    Iteration-3    Smoke
dbConn
    Connect to Database    
    Check if not exists in database    select * from services
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used database library but the documenation says that you need to pass few arguments to `Connect To Database` or have proper configuration file in place. So plase double check your configuration file, or if you are not using one, add proper arguments.

Check the docs for further info:

http://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/api/0.5/DatabaseLibrary.html#Connect%20To%20Database

```
Connect To Database    MySQLdb    my_databse    user    password    db.host.example    port
```

Also make sure you got MySQL driver installed https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/